# how to block xamarin android emulator URLs?

Tags: android, google-chrome, proxy, emulation

When I develop for Android browsers I need to block specific URLs, production URLs, so the current production version won't load. this is causing me quick a headache and lots of issues with 2 code versions loaded.

in iOS, we don't have this issue because the iOS emulator working fine and does use the Mac host file, so production blocked without an issue.

I can't set Proxy for the Android Emulator, just impossible, so it makes it even harder.

any ideas how to block URLs without hacking the Android Virtual Device and set it host file?

Answer (score 1):

after months of trying to bypass this issue I finally found the solution, see here:

[image]

YES! you have request blocker inside Chrome! and it working for all Android Emulators.

it will log all request as "blocked:devtools"

[image]

hope this help,

Nisim